# i cannot install mediapipe in pycharm and mine is 64 bit and python version is 3.11.1

Tags: python, pycharm, mediapipe

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mediapipe (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mediapipe
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpHJb.png)

i tried using "pip install mediapipe" and "py pip install mediapipe" but didn't work.
Also tried using a specific version and went down all the way to 0.8.9 of it in pycharm but the same error pops up

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/solutions/setup_python), Python versions 3.7-3.10 are supported .